# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. Failed to Transform

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting the below error msg, right now I am trying to run the base app only (the one you get from npx react-native init AppName). I have no idea what to do, pls help. it is my first time using android studio and react native so I really have no idea what might be wrong.

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform flipper-0.99.0.aar (com.facebook.flipper:flipper:0.99.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for ExtractAarTransform: C:\Users\ABDUL MANNAN\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\a04738f1860831486d4410af9a53bfae\transformed\jetified-flipper-0.99.0.aar.
         > C:\Users\ABDUL MANNAN\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\a04738f1860831486d4410af9a53bfae\transformed\jetified-flipper-0.99.0.aar (The system cannot find the path specified)
   > Failed to transform flipper-network-plugin-0.99.0.aar (com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:0.99.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.      
      > Execution failed for ExtractAarTransform: C:\Users\ABDUL MANNAN\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\ff42bd2b6bbeeeed875ab569d23f5ccc\transformed\jetified-flipper-network-plugin-0.99.0.aar.
         > C:\Users\ABDUL MANNAN\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\a04738f1860831486d4410af9a53bfae\transformed\jetified-flipper-0.99.0.aar (The system cannot find the path specified)
   > Failed to transform flipper-fresco-plugin-0.99.0.aar (com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.99.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.        
      > Execution failed for ExtractAarTransform: C:\Users\ABDUL MANNAN\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\fbed3863a27a1a52213785ab930d343e\transformed\jetified-flipper-fresco-plugin-0.99.0.aar.
         > C:\Users\ABDUL MANNAN\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\a04738f1860831486d4410af9a53bfae\transformed\jetified-flipper-0.99.0.aar (The system cannot find the path specified)
   > Failed to transform react-native-0.66.0.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.66.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for ExtractAarTransform: C:\Users\ABDUL MANNAN\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\eed5268b74840d3ccc37351259073c8d\transformed\jetified-react-native-0.66.0.aar.
         > C:\Users\ABDUL MANNAN\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\a04738f1860831486d4410af9a53bfae\transformed\jetified-flipper-0.99.0.aar (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I have provided a few lines of the error message, the rest of them are follow the pattern except the .aar package after transform changes.

Comment: were you able to solve this issue? I started experiencing the same after manually clearing out all my caches

Answer (score 2):

Change the Flipper version to `FLIPPER_VERSION=0.125.0` then it will work.

Comment: what does it mean and changing?

Comment: * What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

   > Could not find com.facebook.flipper:flipper:FLIPPER_VERSION=0.125.0.

     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/home/user/prj/node_modules/react-native/android/com/facebook/flipper/flipper/FLIPPER_VERSION=0.125.0/flipper-FLIPPER_VERSION=0.125.0.pom

--

RN ver. is `0.67.4`

Comment: comment flipper and install pod